# AngularJS: Serialize dynamic generated form

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, serialization, dynamic

Writing small web-app with AngularJS. I have form, which is generated dynamically, so I need to serialize it to send data to server. But I faced with problem: when I serialize form, it returns everything, but not serialized data. I don't want to use jQuery, so please can anyone help me to serialize my data only via AngularJS?

Here're codes:

HTML Template:

```
<div ng-controller="DetailsSet as det" ng-init="det.refresh()">
<h1>Editing ({{det.zone}})</h1>
<a ng-href="#{{det.zone}}" class="btn"><i class="m-icon-swapleft"></i> Back</a>

    <form name="det.xform" ng-submit="det.submit()">
        <div ng-repeat="(key,val) in det.formItems" class="control-group">
            <label for="{{key}}" class="control-label">{{val.label}}</label>
            <input type="{{val.type || 'text'}}" ng-model="det.response[key]" class="{{val.class}}" />
        </div>
        <hr />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in det.response"><b>{{key}}</b>: {{value}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
//Details
   .controller('DetailsSet', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
      $scope.params = $routeParams;
      this.zone = $scope.params.zone;
      this.formItems = detailForm[this.zone];
      this.ttl = hdrs[this.zone];

      this.xform = {};

      this.submit = function() {
        console.log(this.xform);
      };

      this.refresh = function() {
        var self = this;
        $http.post('app/route.php', {zone: $scope.params.zone, action: 'show', id: $scope.params.id}).success(function(data) {
          self.response = data[0];
        });
      };

   })
```

Form setup object (just for case):

```
//DetailView Forms
    detailForm = {
        'clients': {
            'clid' : {'type': 'hidden', 'label': null},
            'client_name' : {'label': 'Name'},
      'contact': {'label': 'Contact'},
      'email': {'type':'email', 'label': 'EMail'},
      'phone': {'label': 'Phone'}
        },
        'transaction' : {
            'id' : {'type': 'hidden', 'enabled': false, 'label': null},
      'dat': {'label': 'Дата'},
      'project_id' : {'label':'Project ID'},
      'pay_type_id': {'label': 'Pay type'},
      'summ' : {'type': 'text', 'enabled': true, 'label': 'Sum', 'class':'ssg'},
        },
        'projects' : {
            'pid' : {'type':'hidden', 'enabled': false, 'label': null},
            'project_name' : {'type': 'text', 'enabled': true, 'label': 'Project name'},
      'client_id': {'label': 'Client ID', }
        }
    };
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to serialize / deserialize the request / response data.

Comment: Ok, then what's the best practice to send form data to server?

Comment: $http({method:'POST', url:'/someurl', data: mydata}).then(...);  Where mydata is an object literal (usually bound from returned data retrieved from a GET request).

Comment: And how do I wrap values of form's inputs to mydata?

Answer (score 0):

Found answer by myself, pixelbits shown me the way, and two way bindings should do the trick.

Corrected function is:

```
this.submit = function() {
        console.log(this.response);
      };
```

I'm logging response object, which is changed as I change it in forms.

In case someone gets same problem, here're updated codes:

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="DetailsSet as det" ng-init="det.refresh()">
<h1>Редактирование записи ({{det.zone}})</h1>
<a ng-href="#{{det.zone}}" class="btn"><i class="m-icon-swapleft"></i> Вернуться</a>

    <form name="xform" ng-submit="det.submit()" id="det-form">
        <div ng-repeat="(key,val) in det.formItems" class="control-group">
            <label for="{{key}}" class="control-label">{{val.label}}</label>
            <input type="{{val.type || 'text'}}" ng-model="det.response[key]" value="{{det.response[key]}}" />
        </div>
        <hr />
        <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" />
    </form>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in det.response"><b>{{key}}</b>: {{value}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
   .controller('DetailsSet', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
      $scope.params = $routeParams;
      this.zone = $scope.params.zone;
      this.formItems = detailForm[this.zone];
      this.ttl = hdrs[this.zone];

      this.submit = function() {
        console.log(this.response);
      };

      this.refresh = function() {
        var self = this;
        $http.post('app/route.php', {zone: $scope.params.zone, action: 'show', id: $scope.params.id}).success(function(data) {
          self.response = data[0];
        });
      };

   })
```